# Jquery выборка элементов на стр

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется html код вида

```
<div>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<span></span>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Провожу выборку вот так

```
$("span:nth-child(2)")
```

код не срабатывает. Как правильно производить выборку в jQuery?

Comment: какие именно из спанов тут ожидается быть выбранным?

Comment: К примеру как выбрать 1-ый? и как выбрать 2-ой?

Comment: в вопросе написано _`$("span:nth-child(2)")` - код не срабатывает_ = почему вы решили, что не срабатывает? какой ожидался результат?

Comment: $("span:nth-of-type(2)")

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю вы имели в виду `$('span').eq(2)`

Comment: только 1 - счет от нуля

Comment: или так `$("span:eq(1)")` или так `$("div span:eq(1)")`

Comment: @splash58 Я не знал что так можно.. теперь буду еще хуже относиться к жыквере

Comment: я не хотел испортить ваши отношения :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('span > p:nth-child(2)').html("hi!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <span>
        <p>first</p>
        <p>second</p>
        <p>last</p>
    </span>
    <hr />
    <span>
        <p>first</p>
        <p>second</p>
        <p>last</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child` не зависит от дочерних элементов элемента к которому применяется. Собственно даже в примере у `p` нет дочерних элементов

Comment: @Grundy, ну о чём же вы. span в вопросе пуст. Деток у него нет от слова совсем. Как следствие селектор $("span:nth-child(2)") ведёт в никуда.

Comment: Неа :-) это запрос ведет в никуда, так как нет спана, который **был бы вторым ребенком**, а не потому что у него нет детей

Comment: @Grundy всё верно. я с какого-то перепугу для себя решил, что речь идёт о spam > p.

Answer (score 0):

Например у нас имеется такая разметка:

```
<table>
<tr>    
    <td>FirstName</td>
    <td name="firstName"> Urmuz</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>LastName</td>
    <td name="lastName"> 24</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Выборка по данной схеме:

```
$('td[name=firstName]') // соответствует 'firstName'
$('td[name^=firstName]') // значения, которые начинаются с 'firstName'
$('td[name*=firstName]') // значения, который содержат 'firstName'
```

Думаю данные пример вы сможете применить для своей задачи. Удачного кодинга...

Answer (score 0):

Как указано в [справке](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

`nth-child` выбирает элементы, которые являются n-ми детьми.

Для вашей разметке ни один элемент не имеет вторым ребенком спан, поэтому селектор возвращает 0 элементов.

В приведенном примере, первый спан - является 4 ребенком по счету.

```js
$('span:nth-child(4)').text("hi, i'm fourth span")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="">1</a>
  <a href="">1</a>
  <a href="">1</a>
  <span>1</span>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <span>1</span>
</div>
```

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать селектор [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), либо функцию [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). Важное отличие этих функций - отсчет индексов начинается с 0.

Либо [`nth-of-type`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

```js
$('span:nth-of-type(1)').text("hi, i'm first");
$('span:eq(1)').text("hi, i'm second");
$('span').eq(2).text("hi, i'm third");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>1</span>
</div>
```