# HTML CSS не понятное поведение :not

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```css
.div:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но почему-то, ксс код для отступа слева, не работает для дива, который находится в классе дропдауна, он просто его не видит. Вопрос почему? Он ведь не относится к первому типу (нтх 1).

Comment: Почитай https://webref.ru/css/not

Comment: Так работает псевдоэлемент. 
Все вложенные блоки с классом .div будут как first-child.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Jquery выборка элементов на стр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514665/jquery-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю по промеру смысл поймешь

```css
.div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

div:not(.div) {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="div">div1</div>
  <div class="div">div2</div>
  <div class="div">div3</div>
  <div class="div">div4</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="div">div5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> .div:not(:nth-child(1))

Дословно: класс `.div` за исключением, когда он является первым, дочерним элементом.

Поэтому он не срабатывает в `dropdown`, т.к. `.div` является первым элементом.